Induced morphism of smooth variety to the Grassmannian on global sections?
In Huybrechts & Lehn, The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves, page 143, it reads

Let $X$ be a smooth variety. Suppose $E$ is a locally free sheaf of rank $r$ which is generated by its space of global sections $H:= H^0(X,E)$. The evaulation homomorphism $H\otimes \mathcal{O}_X \to E$ induces a morphism $\varphi: H \to \operatorname{Grass}(H,r)$.

Here, I understood the evaluation homomorphism to be given by $s \otimes 1 \mapsto s(x)$ for each $x\in X$, fiberwise. However, I don't understand how this induces a morphism from $X$ to the Grassmannian of $r$-dimensional subspaces of $H$.
